# UI5: Hide UploadSet's 'No Files Found' Icon

Tags: sapui5, visibility

[image: UploadSet]

In the above image, I would like to hide all (if not most) of the control leaving just the + button (or a little bit of the No Files Found text area) when there are no files uploaded.

I know there's a property noDataText and noDataDescription that can be left blank, but I'd like to hide the large icon to reduce the real estate taken up. How can I achieve this?

Edit: There was a suggestion to use customCSS, how can I do it with that?

Comment: the framework does not offer a build-in way to achieve what you want, but you could simply hide the <li> element with the id of 'attachmentServiceFileUpload-list-nodata'

Comment: Would I input that line of code in a customCSS file? And where did you look to derive that id?

Comment: Yes into your custom CSS file. I used the element inspector to find the id of the thinfg you want to hide :) It's a little 'hacky' but as far as I know there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How To Hide the Icon:**

After exploring, I realize I could right click 'Inspect Element' on the text area and locate the specific part of the control:
[image]

Looking a few lines above at its parent, we see there is a class called sapMUCNoDataPage. Copy it, then press the '+' icon next to :hov and .cls at the top of the right pane.
Then type: `.sapMUCNoDataPage span{display:none}`

[image]

That will hide the icon. Now copy and paste that code, and place it in your style.css file. And that is how you hide the icon.

*P.S. If you don't include the 'span', the whole noFile text area will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the element using CSS:

```
li[id*="attachmentServiceFileUpload-list-nodata"] {
    display: none;
}
```

If you just want to hide it for a specific part in your application you can do the following:

```
div[id*="some-example-detail-page"] li[id*="attachmentServiceFileUpload-list-nodata"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, when I tried using the element inspector, i got id="__set0-list-nodata", and when I put 'set0' instead of 'attachmentServiceFileUpload' the text area was successfully hidden, but it didn't manage to hide when I used the other. How come?

And last question- After the text area was hidden, there was a thin grey line remaining, i've tried hiding it but, can't seem to identify it in the elements inspector. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: I just realized I'm using the UploadCollection, not the UploadSet, that explains the different Ids. The line comes from the `border-bottom` property of the  OverflowToolBar of your UploadSet. Give the OverflowToolbar a css-class with `border-bottom: none` on order to hide the line.